# Variation of functional with area and volume term

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Let $M$ be a closed manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\partial M$ its surface. I want to find (in general terms) the mannifold that minimizes a functional of the form
$$I[M]=\int_{\partial M}f\,\mathrm{d}S+\int_MF\,\mathrm{d}V,$$
for some functions $F,f$. Let $g_{ij}$ be the metric tensor of the mannifold and $g$ its determinant. The volume term is easily rewritten:
$$\int_MF\,\mathrm{d}V=\int F(\vec{x})\sqrt{-g}\,\mathrm{d}^3x,$$
but what should I do with the surface term? The metric tensor is three-dimensional but for the surface integral I need only two dimensions. I've read at some point of induced metrics, they might be what I need. But then again, how do I vary the surface intergral in terms of an induced metric with respect to the actual metric?

Comment: By definition, a closed manifold has no boundary. Did you mean compact manifold?

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have called it manifold $M$, the manifold is actually the surface and what is $M$ is the enclosed volume

Comment: This is all completely muddled. If $M$ is a compact $3$-manifold with boundary in $\Bbb R^3$, then its metric tensor is the standard Euclidean metric. And what is $\sqrt{-g}$?